# Get Camunda TaskID after creation in response

Tags: bpmn, camunda

We are using Camunda for our approval process implementation in our application.
We created a BPMN process with human Task service. We are using the below URL

```
engine-rest/engine/default/process-definition/key/processKey/start
```

we pass our form parameters as input to this service

```
{
"variables": {
"requestId" : {"value" : "xxxxx", "type" : "String"},
"catalog" : {"value" : "yyyy", "type" : "String"},
"businessReason": {"value":"yyyyy","type":"String"},
"link": {"value":"","type":"String"}
}
}
```

The response of this start task is below-

```
{
  "links": [
{
  "method": "GET",
  "href": "http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/engine/default/process-instance/31701",
  "rel": "self"
}
  ],
  "id": "31701",
  "definitionId": "xxxxx:7:31605",
  "businessKey": null,
  "caseInstanceId": null,
  "ended": false,
  "suspended": false,
  "tenantId": null
}
```

The **id** in the response is not the actual task ID which we use to get the task details etc instead its the execution ID.

Is there a way to get the task id back in the response.? Also can we add some parameteres to the above response. Like

```
"status" : "success"
```

I am having listener class created for the Human task but not sure how to add response parameters . Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible unless you build a custom REST resource on top of Camunda's Java API. See https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/reference/rest/overview/embeddability/ for info how you would embed the default REST resources into a custom JAX-RS application.